# How can I shift column values forward if the previous value is in a list of excluded values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have some TSQL code that produces a de-normalized flat file from nicely organized relational tables. The code completes quickly, and the data isn't overwhelming, so chances are any suggestions would help. I don't have to worry much about performance because this process is only intended to be run 1 time a month. I have some wiggle room in that respect.

The source data, for example's sake, is laid out like this: One person (table 1) can have many incidents (table 2). Each incident can have many codes tied to it (table 3). Each code has an ordered sequence. So after flattening this out, one row in the extract file may look like this:

```
Name                IncidentId  Code1   Code2   Code3   Code4
Sue Ellen Crandell  1991        abc1    def1    xyz0    888
```

These de-normalized ordered code columns could potentially go out to over 50. The problem is, that there is a new requirement that if one of the ordered code columns has a value that's in the list of exclusions, then the following ordered code column values should be shifted forward one position. This means that if `def1` was in the exclusion list, the row should look like this:

```
Name                IncidentId  Code1   Code2   Code3   Code4
Sue Ellen Crandell  1991        abc1    xyz0    888     <empty string>
```

Before I fetch additional relational data and export the results to the file, I use dynamic T-SQL to de-normalize these ordered code values into a temp table. Due to not wanting to mess with the dynamic T-SQL, and probable limitations with being able to use conditionals to shift the columns during that part of the process, I'm thinking that the easiest place to put the exclusion list evaluation would be after the ordered code values make it into the temp table.

If I have a temp table that looks like the first data row above, how can I

1. Check each column value.
2. Remove the value if it is included in the exclusion list
3. Conditionally shift values forward when encountering a value in an exclusion list, as shown in the row examples above?

The exclusion list is just a handful of static values that I can either dump into a temp table or use with an `IN` operator. I'm guessing that a CTE might be needed, but the recursion logic isn't clear to me.

Comment: Roughly... normalize it, filter it, denormalise it again, using `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a CTE that unpivots the table so that each code is on a separate row:

```
with cte(Name, IncidentId, CodeName, Code)
as(
    select Name, IncidentId, CodeName, Code
    from Incident i 
    unpivot(Code for CodeName in (Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4)) unpvt
)
```

Now you do an outer join on the CTE to itself, filtering out the excluded codes.  This gives you one row for each Name-Incident-Code tuple, but you have null values in the rows where the code was excluded (you need the null rows to maintain the proper count of codes).

```
Select *, t1.Name, t1.IncidentId, isnull(t2.Code, '') Code, 
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t1.Name, t1.IncidentId order by isnull(t2.CodeName, 'zzz')) CodeNumber
    from cte t1
    left outer join cte t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name and 
           t1.IncidentId = t2.IncidentId and 
           t1.Code = t2.Code and 
           not exists(select 1 from Exclude e where e.Code = t2.Code)
```

The ROW_NUMBER() here will create the new CodeNumber.  The `order byisnull(t2.CodeNumber, 'zzz'))` pushes the null rows to the end so that the rows that have valid codes get numbered first (because "zzz" is greater than "Code-whatever-").

Now you just need to pivot the previous query back so that the codes become columns again:

```
select Name, IncidentId, [1] Code1, [2] Code2, [3] as Code3, [4] as Code4
from
(
    Select t1.Name, t1.IncidentId, isnull(t2.Code, '') Code, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t1.Name, t1.IncidentId order by isnull(t2.CodeName, 'zzz')) CodeNumber
    from cte t1
    left outer join cte t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name and t1.IncidentId = t2.IncidentId and t1.Code = t2.Code and not exists(select 1 from Exclude e where e.Code = t2.Code)
) x
pivot(max(Code) for CodeNumber in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) as pvt
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a198d/4/0)

### Update

There's a couple problems with the code above.  First, when I create the CodeNumber with ROW_NUMBER(), I am sorting by CodeName.  This breaks down after 9 code columns because they no longer sort correctly (they get sorted alphabetically instead of numerically).  So I need to pull the code number out in the CTE so I can use it to sort by later:

```
with cte(Name, IncidentId, CodeName, CodeNumber, Code)
as(
    select Name, IncidentId, CodeName, convert(int, SUBSTRING(CodeName, 5, len(CodeName))), Code
    from Incident i 
    unpivot(Code for CodeName in (Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4, Code5, Code6, Code7, Code8, Code9, Code10)) unpvt
)
```

Now the rest of the query looks like this:

```
select Name, IncidentId, [1] Code1, [2] Code2, [3] as Code3, [4] as Code4, [5] as Code5, [6] as Code6, [7] as Code7, [8] as Code8, [9] as Code9, [10] as Code10
from
(
    Select t1.Name, t1.IncidentId, isnull(t2.Code, '') Code, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t1.Name, t1.IncidentId order by isnull(t2.CodeNumber, 999)) NewCodeNumber
    from cte t1
    left outer join cte t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name and t1.IncidentId = t2.IncidentId and t1.Code = t2.Code and not exists(select 1 from Exclude e where e.Code = t2.Code)
) x
pivot(max(Code) for NewCodeNumber in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
) as pvt
```

Note that since I now have a column called CodeNumber in the CTE, I am calling the newly generated number "NewCodeNumber".  Also, I am ordering by `t2.CodeNumber` instead of `t1.Code`.

Updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a852/5/0).

### Update

Regarding the question in your comment, you're essentially asking about unpivoting multiple columns, which is not as straightforward as unpivoting a single column.  One way to accomplish it is to unpivot the code and the codedate separately:

```
with cteCode(Name, IncidentId, CodeName, CodeNumber, Code)
as(
    select Name, IncidentId, CodeName, convert(int, SUBSTRING(CodeName, 5, len(CodeName))), Code
    from Incident i 
    unpivot(Code for CodeName in (Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4, Code5, Code6, Code7, Code8, Code9, Code10)) unpvt
), cteCodeDate(Name, IncidentId, CodeName, CodeNumber, CodeDate)
as(
    select Name, IncidentId, CodeName, convert(int, SUBSTRING(CodeName, 9, len(CodeName))), CodeDate
    from Incident i 
    unpivot(CodeDate for CodeName in (CodeDate1, CodeDate2, CodeDate3, CodeDate4, CodeDate5, CodeDate6, CodeDate7, CodeDate8, CodeDate9, CodeDate10)) unpvt
)
```

and then join them back together:

```
Select t1.Name, t1.IncidentId, isnull(t2.Code, '') Code, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t1.Name, t1.IncidentId order by isnull(t2.CodeNumber, 999)) NewCodeNumber, t3.CodeDate
    from cteCode t1
    join cteCodeDate t3 on t3.Name = t1.Name and t3.IncidentId = t1.IncidentId and t3.CodeNumber = t1.CodeNumber
    left outer join cteCode t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name and t1.IncidentId = t2.IncidentId and t1.Code = t2.Code and not exists(select 1 from Exclude e where e.Code = t2.Code)
```

Pivoting multiple columns isn't as easy as a single column either, so I went a different route to  get the final result:

```
select Name, IncidentId,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 1 then Code end) Code1,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 1 then CodeDate end) CodeDate1,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 2 then Code end) Code2,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 2 then CodeDate end) CodeDate2,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 3 then Code end) Code3,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 3 then CodeDate end) CodeDate3,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 4 then Code end) Code4,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 4 then CodeDate end) CodeDate4,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 5 then Code end) Code5,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 5 then CodeDate end) CodeDate5,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 6 then Code end) Code6,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 6 then CodeDate end) CodeDate6,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 7 then Code end) Code7,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 7 then CodeDate end) CodeDate7,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 8 then Code end) Code8,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 8 then CodeDate end) CodeDate8,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 9 then Code end) Code9,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 9 then CodeDate end) CodeDate9,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 10 then Code end) Code10,
MAX(case when newCodeNumber = 10 then CodeDate end) CodeDate10
from
(
    Select t1.Name, t1.IncidentId, isnull(t2.Code, '') Code, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t1.Name, t1.IncidentId order by isnull(t2.CodeNumber, 999)) NewCodeNumber, t3.CodeDate
    from cteCode t1
    join cteCodeDate t3 on t3.Name = t1.Name and t3.IncidentId = t1.IncidentId and t3.CodeNumber = t1.CodeNumber
    left outer join cteCode t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name and t1.IncidentId = t2.IncidentId and t1.Code = t2.Code and not exists(select 1 from Exclude e where e.Code = t2.Code)
) x
group by Name, IncidentId
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0a6b/1/0)

Comment: I see a problem in the SQL Fiddle results. The order of the original columns didn't persist. The order of the code columns in the first row, after removing the excluded value(s) should be: abc1, xyz0, 888, where the first column value would hold its position and the columns following the excluded value would shift ahead one position.

Comment: Oops.  The order by in the ROW_NUMBER() should be `order by isnull(t2.CodeName, 'zzz')` instead of `order by isnull(t2.Code, 'zzz')`.  I've updated the answer and the fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a198d/4/0

Comment: Demo looks good. I'm going to try this out by the end of the week.

Comment: Check this out. I may need to have 50 placeholders, but when I test out to just 10 the column value positions don't look right in the results. For whatever reason, some values jump to position 7, 8, etc. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a852/1

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what I can do if I have an accompanying column to each CodeX column (like CodeDateX)? The value of x is the same between the two, and I'd still only evaluate the value of CodeX. However, if a shift is needed, I'd have to push both CodeX and CodeDateX forward.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, Jerrad. The code works! In case this helps anyone else, this is for medical reporting when dealing with certain codes. I just genericized the details a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

This is best handled with dynamic SQL.  Moving things over from column to column to handle exclusions is cumbersome, at best.  It would end up being some variant on:

```
if code1 is not excluded then code1
   else if code2 is not excluded then code2
   else if code3 is not excluded then code3
   else code4 is not excluded then code4 as code1
if code1 is not excluded 
   if code2 is not excluded then code2
   else if code3 is not excluded then code3
   else if code4 is not excluded then code4
and so on, and so on and so on
```

Instead, you probably have a place where you can add something like this to the dynamic SQL:

```
where not exists (select 1 from ExcludedCodes ec where ec.code <> the.code)
```

And you will eliminate them before the pivot.